# filter out observation of a column which start with values of a list

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'code': ['52511', '52512', '12525', '13333']})
```

and the following list:

```
list = ['525', '13333']
```

I want to consider only the observations of `df` that start witht the element of `list`.

Desired output:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'code': ['52511', '52512', '13333']})
```

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html

Comment: str.startswith does not take as argument a list

Answer (score 0):

The startswith function supports tuple type. You can convert list to tuple.

```
listt = ['525', '13333']
df=df[df['code'].str.startswith(tuple(listt))]
df
'''
    code
0   52511
1   52512
3   13333

'''
```